# XMLUnit NodeFilter not finding difference

Tags: xmlunit-2

Comparing two simple XMLs and want to compare nodes with specific localName. In this case only `flowerA`. When i use not equals to `flowerB` it gives me the difference for `flowerA` node, when i say equals to `flowerA` it doesnt give any difference?

```
    public class XMLDiff {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String controlXml = "<flowers><flowerA>Rose</flowerA><flowerB>Daisy</flowerB></flowers>";
            String testXml =    "<flowers><flowerA>Roses</flowerA><flowerB>Daisies</flowerB></flowers>";

            Diff build = DiffBuilder.compare(controlXml).withTest(testXml)
                    .ignoreWhitespace()
                    .withNodeFilter(node -> !node.getNodeName().equals("flowerB"))
                    .build();
            System.out.println(build.getDifferences());
        }
    }
```

```
[Expected text value 'Rose' but was 'Roses' - comparing <flowerA ...>Rose</flowerA> at /flowers[1]/flowerA[1]/text()[1] to <flowerA ...>Roses</flowerA> at /flowers[1]/flowerA[1]/text()[1] (DIFFERENT)]
```

```
    public class XMLDiff {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String controlXml = "<flowers><flowerA>Rose</flowerA><flowerB>Daisy</flowerB></flowers>";
            String testXml =    "<flowers><flowerA>Roses</flowerA><flowerB>Daisies</flowerB></flowers>";

            Diff build = DiffBuilder.compare(controlXml).withTest(testXml)
                    .ignoreWhitespace()
                    .withNodeFilter(node -> node.getNodeName().equals("flowerA"))
                    .build();
            System.out.println(build.getDifferences());
        }
    }
```

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root element `flowers` is not matched by the `NodeFilter` and so you end up with comparing nothing at all.

`NodeFilter` is best suited for a deny list of nodes you do not want to compare. In your case you need to ensure you also allow all nodes that are encountered while traversing to the node you are interested in.